# How to make the "Pictures" folder a folder again

Tags: macos, finder, photos.app, folders

#### Question:

Is it possible to change a package directory into an ordinary directory, and how?

#### Context:

I was copying an old iPhoto library to my "~/Pictures" folder from an external drive, but I somehow made a mistake as only the subdirectories of the iPhoto library were copied over.

I tried making a new ".photolibrary" directory and moving the subdirectories into that, but the system still thinks that my Pictures folder is a ".photolibrary" directory. It comes up as a "package" rather than as a folder now, meaning I can only access it throught the command line or by choosing "show package contents" in Finder.

Also, when I tried renaming the new photolibrary to be the same as the old one, I get an error message saying that there already exists a directory with that name, even though there doesn't. I'm guessing the Pictures folder/package somehow comes up as having the name of my old photolibrary after I copied it over.

#### Edit:

I am using OSX version 10.9, so I don't think SIP applies.

```
ls -dle@ ~/Pictures 
drwxrwxrwx@ 131 User  staff  4454 19 Jun 01:37 /Users/User/Pictures
com.apple.FinderInfo      32
com.apple.quarantine      21
0: group:everyone deny delete
```

This is what comes up when I do "get info" on my Pictures folder:

[image]

Comment: I see two thing wrong with the Pictures Info sheet, one its shown as a package and Open with: Terminal, neither of which should even be there.  What's the output of the following command in Terminal: `ls -dle@ ~/Pictures`

Answer (score 1):

*Using answer space to provide pictures...*

Get Info on both your Pictures & Photos Library directories, make sure they are named as below, Pictures & Photos Library.photoslibrary
Also check whether the extension is hidden for only the Library & whether something managed to rename it with a double extension .photoslibrary.photoslibrary - which has been known to happen.

[image]

The Pictures directory ought to be protected by SIP & not allow you to change it. Post a comment below if the Pictures naming is wrong & you need to change it.
Photos Library can be renamed at will [though Photos.app may lose it until you tell it where to look]

To look inside the package, you can just right click it & Show Package Contents, however, the .photoslibrary structure can be toggled between a regular folder & package by adding/removing the .photoslibrary extension then rebooting.

Post a comment if I missed anything & I'll tweak my answer.

Comment: This looks a good answer. :-)

Comment: You said, "_The Pictures directory ought to be protected by SIP_" and while you answered before the OP edit showing OS X 10.9, which of course doesn't use SIP, nonetheless even in SIP enabled version of OS X SIP has nothing to do with the User's Picture Folder. See [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) to see what's covered by SIP.  That said, the Picture Folder does have an ACL applied: `0: group:everyone deny delete`

Comment: @user3439894 - sure - it was never really meant to be a fully-qualified answer, I just wanted to be able to see the difference between what ought to be & what actually was. Thanks for the heads-up on how the Pics folder is actually protected, by ACL, I wasn't aware of that - my nix knowledge is still a little rudimentary, but I'm learning... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an apple discussions page where another user has the same problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2586142?tstart=0

This problem is due to the fact that OS X has what's called a "bundle bit" that determines whether a folder is a bundle or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `~/Pictures` folder is showing two extended attributes it shouldn't have, `com.apple.FinderInfo` which is probably holding the *bundle bit* and `com.apple.quarantine`. In a Terminal use the following commands to remove both extended attributes that shouldn't be there.

```
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo ~/Pictures
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/Pictures
```

No need to deal with Developer Tools at this point as removing the extended attributes with `xattr`, which is already a part of OS X, will do the job.

Note that the reason I said "which is probably holding the *bundle bit*" because without seeing the output of `xattr -l ~/Pictures` to compare, then under the circumstances I'm logically assuming that's the info being held.

In any case the `~/Pictures` folder should not have any extended attributes set and, aside from the normally expected output, only the ACL of `0: group:everyone deny delete` is appropriate output of `ls -dle@ ~/Pictures` I asked for.