# How to recover .photoslibrary files in an erased partition?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, recovery, data-recovery

I made a mistake in which I erased an external drive with some originals .photoslibrary files that were not backuped.

I am using in this moment [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to retrieve the lost files (appointed as being placed in a HFSX partition by [R-Studio](https://www.r-studio.com/data_recovery_macintosh/) for mac (do not confuse it with the statistics software R-Studio).

The point is that in the outcome of photorec software I am receiving thousands of files completely messed up, obviously without names and dates, and I'm wondering that if I could retrieve only .photoslibrary files, usually easily located for their often gigabyte-sized characteristic, it would be the best solution ever.

The point is: apparently none of these file-recovery softwares are able to locate and to find .photoslibrary files, perhaps because [it is a package or treated like a directory in some way.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243127/how-to-make-the-pictures-folder-a-folder-again).

I would appreciate any way of locating and restoring .photoslibrary files or if I could in some way rebuild my HFSX partition securely in order to access my lost drive again.

Comment: Is the external drive a mechanical (spinning) drive or is it an SSD?  It matters, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388780/119271).  Also, what recovery software did you try?  What were the results?  Can you post screen shots?

Comment: @Allan he used photorec for his recovery software.

Comment: @Allan, fortunatelly, in this case, it is a HDD (magnetic disc). I'm already retrieving (thousands of) files from it, but in a complete mess. My hope is to discover a way to retrieve .photoslibrary that would me lead straight to the point. I used R-studio to get a first glance of the problem while I was learning to work with photorec. R-studio is paid software. For this reason I choose to get through the process with photorec.

Comment: what version of macOS software

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.4. @Allan.